# How to use PHP excel Class to generate excel files in Zend Framwork?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, spreadsheet-excel-writer

I am new to zend framwork, previously worked on cakePHP. I have used ExcelWriter by creating a component. but I dont think Zend having such kind of facilities or not.

Can anyone help me in this case?
My Component Code to be used with Zend [Link](https://gist.github.com/anuluvi/cf1bd6c282c869f8493d49c5d3eb02ba)

Comment: ZF2 doesn't have any spreadsheet generator component. But there is plenty of librairies that doing a such thing. You can take a look at : https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Comment: You have to bring your component under a namespace, after that you can use autoload_classmap.php of your {Module Folder} to point that namespace. After successfully add your namespace you can use that component anywhere of your MODULE.